# Find the area ratio of the $ABNM$ and $ABCD$ trapezoids

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In the trapezoid $ABCD$ ($AB \parallel CD$), $MN$ is the median. $NP$ is traced parallel to $AD$ ($P \in CD$). The area of ​​$MNCD$ is $16\ \mathrm{m^2}$ and that
> of the triangle $NCP$ is $4\ \mathrm{m^2}$. Calculate the area ratio of the trapezoids $ABNM$ and $ABCD$. (Answer:$\frac{1}{3}$)

My progress: I found the following relationships.

$h$ = height of trapezoid:

$S_{CPN}=4=\frac{CP\cdot h}{4}\implies CP\cdot h  =16$

$S_{ABCD} = MN\cdot h = \frac{AB+CD}{2}\cdot H$

$S_{AMBN} = \frac{AB+MN}{2}\cdot\frac{h}{2}$

$S_{PDMF} = S_{AEMF}=FM\cdot\frac{h}{2}$

$S_{PCFN} = \frac{FN\cdot h}{4}$

$\frac{S_{DCMN}}{S_{MNAB}}=\frac{MN^2-CD^2}{AB^2-MN^2}(\text{ property})$

$\frac{S_{AMNB}}{S_{ABCD}}=\frac{\frac{(AB+MN)\cdot h}{4}}{MN\cdot h}=
\frac{AB+MN}{4MN} = \frac{3AB+CD}{4(AB+CD)}$

...???

[image]

Comment: that is a trapezium, not a trapezoid

Comment: @hellofriends in the united staes is a trapezoide..in UK is a trapezium,,A trapezoid (called a trapezium in the UK) has a pair of opposite sides parallel.

And a trapezium (called a trapezoid in the UK) is a quadrilateral with NO parallel sides:

Comment: I don't think there is a fixed ratio but I will check further

Comment: Triangle $NCP$ has no role in the question: there must be something wrong in the text.

Comment: Moreover, the ratio of those two trapezoids can never be $1/3$, unless one of them is a triangle.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca   
It is possible that the answer is wrong or even the statement... it is not uncommon in these exercises. I changed the text of the question because it was mentioned $NP \parallel AD$ to $EP \parallel AD$ because I didn't see sense in the original text,

Comment: $NP\parallel AD$ does make sense.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca But $P$ would then be in the $CD$ prolongation...I figured it should be between $C$ and $D$ but if that helps the resolution then it is

Comment: The result is easy to prove. Just make the right sketch, with $CD>AB$ and $NP\parallel AD$. Then add a line through $B$, also parallel to $AD$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof without words...............................

[image]